# Which presentationTimeUs to use in Media Codec if I'm not using MediaExtractor?

Tags: android

I'm not using a MediaExtractor because I'm getting data directly from RTSP by a library. Therefore I have no information on timestamps. What should be the value of [presentationTimeUs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#queueInputBuffer(int,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20int)) in

```
public void queueInputBuffer (int index, 
                int offset, 
                int size, 
                long presentationTimeUs, 
                int flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

`presentationTimeUs` must have timestamp in microseconds for encoded frame. It is used by renderer (player) to detect when to show this frame. Usually the time from the beginning of encoding is put there in microseconds. You can calculate it as `now - encodingStartTime`