# Attaching Surface to MediaCodec (NDK) gives GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

```
MediaCodecDecoder::MediaCodecDecoder(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaSurface, Codec codec)
{
    this->codec = codec;
    std::string mime = "video/avc";
    if (env && !env->IsSameObject(javaSurface, NULL))
    {
        this->surface.reset(ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, javaSurface));
        format.reset(AMediaFormat_new());
        AMediaFormat_setString(format.get(), AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, mime.c_str());
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format.get(), AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, 2304);
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format.get(), AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, 1296);
        aMediaCodec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mime.c_str());
        media_status_t mediaCodecStatus = AMediaCodec_configure(aMediaCodec,
                                                                format.get(),
                                                                surface.get(),
                                                                nullptr,
                                                                0);
        AMediaCodec_start(aMediaCodec);
    }
}

void MediaCodecDecoder::run()
{

    while(shouldContinue()) {
        ssize_t bufferIndex = -1;
        //Gets new RTSP packet
        std::shared_ptr<EncodedPacket> encodedPacket = onAcquireNewPacket();
        bufferIndex = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(aMediaCodec, 5000);
        if (bufferIndex >= 0) {
            size_t bufferSize;
            auto buffer = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer(aMediaCodec, bufferIndex, &bufferSize);

            if (encodedPacket->getSize() < bufferSize) {
                memcpy(buffer, encodedPacket->getFramePointer(), encodedPacket->getSize());
            }

            AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(aMediaCodec, bufferIndex, 0, encodedPacket->getSize(),
                                         10000, 0);
        }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
I/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) init name(video/avc) isType(1) encoder(0)
I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
I/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) Component Allocated (OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc)
I/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) configure surface(0x7f56270000) crypto(0x0) flags(0)
D/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) configure format: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
          string mime = "video/avc"
          int32_t width = 2304
          int32_t height = 1296
        }
D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7f56270010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 20434946
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x7f56270010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
    connecting to surface 0x7f56270010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/ACodec: DRC Mode: Dynamic Buffer Mode
I/ExtendedACodec: setupVideoDecoder()
I/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setupVideoDecoder Width Height (2304x1296)
    mime (video/avc) compressionFormat (7)
I/ExtendedACodec: Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
I/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) start
D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7f56270010 for 2304x1296, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
I/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) kWhatStartCompleted
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/chatty: uid=10102(u0_a102) CodecLooper identical 2 lines
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7f5ba36010 for 2304x1296, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
D/MediaCodec: (0x7f589bac00) kWhatOutputBuffersChanged
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7f56270010 for 1920x1088, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
D/MediaCodec: (0x7f589ba200) kWhatOutputBuffersChanged
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/chatty: uid=10102(u0_a102) CodecLooper identical 2 lines
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
Process 19956 terminated.
```

If I take off the `format.get()` in `AMediaCodec_configure` and put `nullptr` into there, I get no     `W/GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000` errors, **so the problem is in** `javaSurface` **for sure**.

I tried to make `javaSurface` a global reference:

```
this->globalJavaSurface = env->NewGlobalRef(javaSurface);
this->surface.reset(ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, globalJavaSurface));
```

but I still get the error.

The Surface that arrives at `MediaCodecDecoder`'s constructor is created from a `SurfaceTexture` that is attached to the screen: `Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);`

As you can see by the output, decoding is working because it detects the width and height of the 2 streams I added.

ps: note that I'm calling queueInputBuffer with presentationTimeoutUS equal to 10000 because I don't know what to put there: [Which presentationTimeUs to use in Media Codec if I'm not using MediaExtractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732992/which-presentationtimeus-to-use-in-media-codec-if-im-not-using-mediaextractor) but I don't think  this is a problem here